# cумма простых чисел golang

Tags: golang, простые-числа

пользоатель вводит число, программа выводит два простых числа, которые образуют сумму раннее введёного числа.
Как сделать?
Уже есть часть кода, которая выводит все простые числа до 100

```
package main

import ("math"; "fmt")

const n = 100

func main() {
fmt.Print(1, " ", 2)
L:  for i := 3; i <= n; i += 2 {
    m := int(math.Floor(math.Sqrt(float64(i))))
    for j := 2; j <= m; j++ {
        if i%j == 0 {
                continue L
        }
    }
    fmt.Print(" ", i)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720904/how-to-find-a-number-as-a-sum-of-prime-numbers

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8